# How connect Olingo4 with MySql or another jdbc

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc, olingo

I am a beginner in Olingo. 

I would like to understand Olingo4. how I can connect him to jdbc (MySql)? 
In olingo v2 - I was connected.
I thought that time in v2 everything is good, and in v4 has to be realized, but I haven't found it.

Thank you very much

Comment: Olingo is an implementation of OData specification. It's just a specification for REST web services and it does not define how you should handle the processed filters. It's up to you to design how you provide the connections, result set mapping etc. from the back end.

Answer (score 1):

When using JDBC, there is no direct correlation between Olingo and your JDBC service.

All your Olingo framework will do is to provide a servlet which will handle incoming OData requests. You will for example have a method which will process requests of the following structure: `/EntityCollection`, another for processing requests of this structure: `/EntityCollection(1)`, and so on.

These methods will determine what data was asked for, then query the database layer (to which you will connect using JDBC), then structure that data and return it to the user.

All you need to do, then, is have some classes which will query the database (think DAO classes) and call these from your Olingo servlet.

Comment: May be you know How I can createServiceMetadata with Annotation?